# Why do LLMs like GPT-3 or Bloom use Vanilla Transformer instead of long sequence variants like Transformer-XL?

Tags: transformer, large-language-models

Is there any particular reason that the most recent and successful large language models like GPT-3 or Bloom utilize a vanilla Transformer architecture instead of an arguably superior long sequence architecture like, e.g. Transformer-XL, LongFormer, BigBird, etc.?

In case you have any ideas or insights, please let me know.